# Restricting enum raw type by conformance to protocol requirements

Tags: swift

I'm trying to enforce a restriction where an enum conforming to a specific protocol can only have a particular raw type. More specifically, I have a protocol that I want enums to conform to, but I need to ensure that the enums' raw type matches a specific type, such as Int (defined by protocol).

I tried few things, like:

```
protocol IntRawValueEnum {
    associatedtype RawValue: BinaryInteger = Int
}

enum MyEnum: IntRawValueEnum {
   typealias RawValue = Int
}
```

and it kinda works, but compiler errors are kinda misleading, and don't point out what is important.

What I wanted to achieve, is something like, when you implement this protocol, compiler says, this enum's raw type has to be Int.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: The error message I get for `enum MyEnum: String, IntRawValueEnum` is "Type 'MyEnum' does not conform to protocol 'IntRawValueEnum'". That is misleading to you? Really?

Comment: @Sweeper I got this one `MyEnum' declares raw type 'String', but does not conform to RawRepresentable and conformance could not be synthesized`. It's not a misleading, I used wrong word, sorry. But I was hoping of some more obvious error message.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Make sense.. Even the code above kinda works :/

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Technically, OP mentioned nothing about restricting conforming types to *only enums*. It only says "*if*" an enum conforms to the protocol, its raw value must be `Int`.

Comment: @malhal I have undeleted it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add an extra requirement to `IntRawValueEnum`, that conforming types must also conform to `RawRepresentable` (which enums with raw values do), then you can add a requirement for `RawRepresentable.RawValue` too.

```
protocol IntRawValueEnum: RawRepresentable where RawValue == Int {
    
}
```

For an enum with a different raw value type, e.g.

```
enum MyEnum: String, IntRawValueEnum {
    case a
}
```

This produces 2 errors:

> 'IntRawValueEnum' requires the types 'String' and 'Int' be equivalent

> Type 'MyEnum' does not conform to protocol 'IntRawValueEnum'

The first one should be clear enough to tell that the `: String` part should be `: Int` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I wanted more restrictions. Thank you, this message (IMO) is a bit more precise about what is the protocol requirement.